# Proving $\operatorname{coker}(f^*) \cong (\ker f)^*$ for a linear map $f$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, dual-spaces, vector-space-isomorphism, dual-maps

> Let $f: V \to W$ be linear and $V, W$ be vector spaces of finite dimension. I want to show that the cokernel, defined by $\operatorname{coker}(f^*) := V^* / \operatorname{im}(f^*)$, is isomorphic to $(\ker f)^*$.

I already tried to use the rank and nullity theorem

$$\dim \operatorname{coker} f^* = \dim V^* - \dim \operatorname{im}f^* \iff \dim V^* = \dim \operatorname{coker} f^*+\dim \operatorname{im}f^*$$

and maybe one could show $\dim \operatorname{im} f^* = \dim \operatorname{im}f$ and thus

$$\dim \operatorname{coker} f^* = \dim \ker f = \dim (\ker f)^*.$$ 
But how can I prove that the dimensions of the images of $f$ and $f^*$ and the dimensions of $\ker f$ and $(\ker f)^*$ are equal? Is this anyway the right way to prove it?

Comment: It should probably be $\operatorname{coker}(f^*) := V^* / \operatorname{im}(f^*)$.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I edited it.

Comment: You should specify that you are using finite dimensions. The dual space is much larger (dimensionally speaking) than the original space when you have infinite dimensional spaces.

Comment: Yes. True. Thank you @ArturoMagidin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to take a look at the restriction map $V^*\to (\operatorname{ker} f)^*$, and show that it factors to a map $\operatorname{coker}(f^*)\to (\operatorname{ker} f)^*$.

Then you can use dimension arguments to show that it is an isomorphism.

Comment: What do you mean by "show that it factors to a map"?

Comment: I mean that the map defined on $V^*$ induces a map on its quotient.

Comment: Okay. Then, seeing $V^* / (\ker f)^* \cong \operatorname{im} f$
$$\dim (\operatorname{im} f)^* = \dim V^* - \dim(\ker f)^*$$
and thus
$$ \dim \operatorname{coker} f^* = \dim V^* - \dim \operatorname{im} f^* = \dim (\ker f)^* $$
and the prove is done. Right? Is $\operatorname{im} f^* = (\operatorname{im} f)^*$?

Comment: Sorry, but what is the purpose of the both maps then? This prove works without them, doesn't it? Is there a error in reasoning in my thought?

Comment: The point is that you don't want to prove that the two spaces are abstractly isomorphic. You want to show that there is an explicit canonical isomorphism.

Comment: But then I don't really get how I can construct the isomorphism...

Comment: Sorry for asking but dual spaces are very new to me.

Answer (score 2):

Define $\Phi: V^*\to (\ker f)^*$ by $\Phi(x^*)=x^*|_{\ker f}$ for all $x^*\in V^*$. It is easy to see that $\Phi$ is a surjective linear map. Now if $x^*= f^*(y^*)$ for some $y^*\in W^*$ then $x^*|_{\ker f}(x)=y^*(f(x))=y^*(0)=0$ for all $x\in \ker f$.

Now, suppose $x^*|_{\ker f}(x)=0$ for all $x\in\ker f$. Let $\mathcal{B}$ be a basis of $\text{im}(f)$, and $\mathcal{B}'$ be
a basis of $W$ containing $\mathcal{B}$.  Define $y^*(y)=x^*(x)$ if
$y\in \mathcal{B}$ and $y=f(x)$, and $y^*(y)=0$ if
$y\in\mathcal{B}'\setminus\mathcal{B}$.  Then, extend $y^*$ to the
whole $W$ by linearity.  It follows that $y^*$ is a well defined
linear functional in $W^*$. Also, it should be easy to verify that $f^*(y^*)=x^*$. Thus, $\ker \Phi={\rm im}(f^*)$. Now,  use the first isomorphism theorem to conclude.

Comment: I think the definition of $y^*$ needs to be corrected.  I think you need to fix a basis of $\text{im}(f)$ and extend it to a basis of $W$, and then define $y^*(y)$ for $y$ in this basis instead.  (I am not sure what $X$ is.  Is it $V$?)  However, overall, your answer looks good.  You have a canonical isomorphism, which does not assume finite-dimensionality.

Comment: I think it should be defined like this.  Let $\mathcal{B}$ be a basis of $\text{im}(f)$, and $\mathcal{B}'$ be a basis of $W$ containing $\mathcal{B}$.  Define $y^*(y)=x^*(x)$ if $y\in \mathcal{B}$, and $y^*(y)=0$ if $y\in\mathcal{B}'\setminus\mathcal{B}$.  Then, extend $y^*$ to the whole $W$ by linearity.  It follows that $y^*$ is a well defined linear functional in $W^*$.

Comment: I don't mind if you use my argument to replace your definition of $y^*$ completely (so people don't get confused when reading your solution).  So, let me change your answer to get rid of the old definition.